# Sleeping Symbolic Term in and Expression

Tags: symbolic

Hello I have some code that have terms that look like `g2''[y] E^[n I x]` where `n` is 0,1,2,... I would like for when `n=0` for the `E^[0 I x]` terms to stay as `E^[0 I x]` and not be changed to one. For example, in symbolic calculations if I were to input into Mathematica

`g2''[y] E^[0 I x]`

it returns

`g2''[y]`

where I would rather it return

`g2''[y] E^[0 I x]`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this without holding the expression, since Mathematica will automatically replace $e^{i 0 x}$ with $1$.

```
ClearAll[g, y, n, x];
Table[With[{n = n}, 
  g''[y] If[n == 0, HoldForm@Exp[n I x], Exp[n I x]]], {n, 0, 4}]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But under the cover, $e^{i 0 x}$ is wrapped with `HoldForm` and it is stuck with it until you remove the hold, then it goes back to $1$

```
 InputForm[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]